# Sharing common functionality/configuration across multiple angularjs projects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple angularjs projects in place, each containing multiple pages.
I need to share some common configuration for $http which contains some common configuration setting and a response interceptor across these projects.
How can I share this common piece across multiple angularjs projects. Each project loads angularjs and is being built by getting bower_dependencies.

I will not know the absolute path at which the module is present from each project.

Specifically, I need to set withCredentials to true and set some common headers in request and set common response interceptor for all the projects. Is there a way to share this?

Can I build a common angularjs module out of this, if yes then how will that work with bower_dependencies in place?

Comment: You might split it into 2 parts:  If you use grunt, then use something like grunt-ng-constant which can take configuration properties and create an config module you can inject wherever you need it.  Then make a separate project for the response interceptor module and have each of your angular projects pull in that response interceptor module via bower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the config phase

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
     // REST OF DEFAULTS
}]);
```

Read more about `$httpProvider` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is why modules are so convenient

Each module can have it's own config or run phase, services etc so wrapping what you need into one module and injecting that module into multiple projects is no different than the other third party modules that you already use.

```
angular.module('myUniversalModule', [])
  .constant('someconstant',123)
  .factory('myUniversalInterceptor', function() {
    var myInterceptor = {
      ....      
    };
    return myInterceptor;

  }).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myUniversalInterceptor');
      $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }
  ]);
```

Then inject in any app

```
angular.module('thisMainApp', ['myUniversalModule'])
       .config(....
       .run(....
       .factory(....
       .constant(...
       .controller(...
```